# Azure msal ClientAuthError Help @azure/msal-node

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to follow the tutorial for [Microsoft active-directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal)

After inputting the client ID and secret into the code and running the code, it takes me to the login page where I login with the credentials but I get the following error:

```
"errorCode": "request_cannot_be_made",
"errorMessage": "Token request cannot be made without authorization code or refresh token.",
"subError": "",
"name": "ClientAuthError"
```

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: Hi, @b.b.89. Does my reply help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code works well: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-node/

When using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), we need to get authorization code with [`getAuthCodeUrl()`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-node/blob/main/index.js#L42) first, then obtain the access token with the authorization code by [`acquireTokenByCode()`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-node/blob/main/index.js#L54). You may miss getting authorization code, please check yours.

**Notes:**

1. Set Supported account types as "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts". **If not**, change 'common' in authority with your tenant-id.
2. **redirectUri** in the sample code needs to be the same as **Redirect URI** in the portal.

Comment: Had same issue and Note 2 worked for me :) thankyou @Pamela Peng

Comment: point 1 saved me. I had selected just: "Personal accounts"